# char list from 0 to f

Tags: python, shortest-path

I write a python script, which needs a list of all hexadecimal characters.

Is it a good idea to do `list(string.printable[:16])` to get `['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with doing that.

Comment: How about [Hex digits](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.hexdigits)

Comment: @GarbageCollector nice one, but it prints `'0123456789abcdefABCDEF'`. It's done for testing, not generating lists. of course you could slice it.

Comment: @PM2Ring rather: `string.hexdigits[:16]`

Comment: Wow, I didn't see string.hexdigits. It is more understandable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be a list comprehension of all numbers from 0 to 15 formatted as hex:

```
["{:x}".format(x) for x in range(0,16)]
```

User GarbageCollector suggested a nice alternative in comments, which must be adapted to remove the redundant, uppercased chars:

```
>>> import string
>>> string.hexdigits
'0123456789abcdefABCDEF'
>>> string.hexdigits[:16]
'0123456789abcdef'
```

to get a list:

```
>>> list(string.hexdigits[:16])
```

the fact that the order of the characters remains the same in `string.hexdigits` in future python version is however unknown. Still nice to know that `string` has some many useful characters groups.

Comment: yes, why not. GarbageCollector should have answered as well.

Answer (score 2):

How about doing `list('0123456789abcdef')` to make it explicit?

If you don't want to spell it out, `[f'{i:x}' for i in range(16)]` should also work.

Comment: `[format(i, 'x') for i in range(16)]` is better than slicing the value returned by `hex`. Or in Python 3.6+, `[f'{i:x}' for i in range(16)]`

Comment: I guess so. I still think the first solution is the best, as per PEP-10, but I'll edit in your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your question is: it is not a particularly good idea.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html):

> `string.printable`
>
> String of ASCII characters which are considered printable. This is a combination of [`digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits), [`ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters), [`punctuation`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation), and [`whitespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.whitespace).

An implementation of Python could follow this definition, but choose to provide the characters in a different order, which could break your code.

Even if the order were defined, it would not be obvious without being familiar with the definition, what result the code would produce.

There is a [`string.hexdigits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.hexdigits) constant, whose value is strictly defined as `'0123456789abcdefABCDEF'`, so taking the first 16 digits of that would definitely be a better choice, but I would still say that just giving the exact string itself would be clearer.

Also note that `'01234567890abcdef'` is actually two characters shorter than `string.hexdigits[:16]` anyway.

Comment: Perfect, that's why I asked